# Extra whitespace area at the bottom side of a Popup, it does not resize correctly to fit its content height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

In a User Control I have below content:

```
   <Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           StaysOpen="False"
           PlacementTarget="mouse"
           Placement="Bottom">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle MinWidth="40" Fill="#fff" Stroke="#BEBEBE"/>
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontSize="12"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="#666666"
                       Margin="12,15,12,0"
                       MinWidth="100"
                       MaxWidth="150"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       UseLayoutRounding="True"
                       Text="{Binding Path=someText}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontSize="12"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Foreground="#666666"
                       Margin="12,8,12,10"
                       MinWidth="100"
                       MaxWidth="150"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       UseLayoutRounding="True"
                       Text="{Binding Path=moreText}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Button x:Name="CloseBtn"
                    Content="Ok"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#BEBEBE"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="5"
                    Padding="5"
                    Click="Close_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    </Popup>
   </Grid>
```

This produces the follwowing window when button is shown:

[image]

and this another one when button is not shown:

[image]

The button in the window sometimes is visible and sometimes not (making it visible or collapsed respectively), it depends on some conditions. This is make visible or not in code-behind.

When the button is collapsed and not visible, the remaining space at the bottom of the window is removed as expected, the window resizes fine both its height and width according to its content. All works ok. This is just what I want, I mean, the window to be resizable to fit its content without leaving remaining whitespace areas. This is perfect.

Now, instead of a rectangle, I replace it with a path because I want it to be displayed as a speech bubble with an arrow pointing to the target. This path data is created dynamically at run time each time the stackpanel changes its size (I have added a SizeChanged event to the stack panel). See below how it is with this modification (Below code is the same as above but using a path instead of rectangle):

```
   <Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           StaysOpen="False"
           PlacementTarget="mouse"
           Placement="Bottom">
    <Grid>
        <!-- <Rectangle MinWidth="40" Fill="#fff" Stroke="#BEBEBE"/> -->
        <Path x:Name="myPath" Visibility="Hidden"
              Fill="White"
              Stroke="#BEBEBE"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
              UseLayoutRounding="True">
        </Path>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                    SizeChanged="StackPanel_SizeChanged">
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontSize="12"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="#666666"
                       Margin="12,15,12,0"
                       MinWidth="100"
                       MaxWidth="150"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       UseLayoutRounding="True"
                       Text="{Binding Path=someText}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontSize="12"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Foreground="#666666"
                       Margin="12,8,12,10"
                       MinWidth="100"
                       MaxWidth="150"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       UseLayoutRounding="True"
                       Text="{Binding Path=moreText}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <Button x:Name="CloseBtn"
                    Content="Ok"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#BEBEBE"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="5"
                    Padding="5"
                    Click="Close_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    </Popup>
   </Grid>
```

In the StackPanel_SizeChanged event I create a path Data in code-behind that then I associate to the path in the xaml view. The code in the StackPanel_SizeChanged event is the following:

```
private void StackPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double width = e.NewSize.Width;
    double height = e.NewSize.Height;

    string stringPathData = $"M8,7.41 L15.415,0 L22.83,7.41 L{width},7.41 L{width},{height} L0,{height} L0,7.41 L8,7.41";
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Geometry));
    this.myPath.Data = (Geometry)converter.ConvertFrom(stringPathData);
}
```

Path is drawn correctly around the window. But now the window does not adjust to fit its content. It fits the content width correctly but not the height. A whitespace area is kept at the bottom side of the window even when button is collapsed. See below:

[image]

I have observed that the window always keeps the largest height. I mean if I put some large text and after that a shorter text in the window, window maintains the largest height (in this case the first correponding to the large text) so this produces a whitespace are at the bottom side of the window. It looks like that when changing from a larger text to a shorter text the StackPanel_SizeChanged event does not get fired (well in fact it does not fire, I have debugged it). So I get the following independently if button is shown or not:

[image]

[image]

The close button event Close_Click is the following:

```
private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (popup != null)
    {
        this.CloseBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        myPopup.IsOpen = false;
        myPopup.StaysOpen = false;
    }
}
```

I need the window to fit its content height and width.

PS. Please, if you have any doubts or questions or it is not clear for you, let me know before you spent your time reproducing it.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, that the Stackpanel doesnt get rezised? In that case reloading the Popup when the text is changed should help.
Otherwise you could rezise the Popup manually which then resizes the Stackpanel (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f98226ae-31d9-47da-a69a-687659378c94/how-to-resize-a-popup-in-wpf?forum=wpf).